# Cannot connect to Github?

Tags: git, http, networking, github, push

so I tried to push some updates onto my repo on github via terminal on Mac OSX 10.8.4 and it doesn't work.

I've been getting the same error many times:

> Lillys-MacBook-Air:Yuewei Lilly$ git push origin master
>   error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation timed out while accessing https://github.com/lillybeans/Yuewei.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
>   fatal: HTTP request failed

Some background:

1. I've pushed many projects onto github before using terminal (when I was in Canada).
2. I am currently in Shanghai, China, could it be the GFW? But when I was in Beijing, I was able to push projects onto github still.
3. when I do ping github.com:

> Lillys-MacBook-Air:Yuewei Lilly$ ping github.com
>   
> PING github.com (192.30.252.131): 56 data bytes
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
>   
> ping: sendto: No route to host
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
>   
> ping: sendto: Host is down
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
>   
> ping: sendto: Host is down
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
>   
> ping: sendto: Host is down
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
>   
> ping: sendto: Host is down
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
>   
> ping: sendto: Host is down
>   
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
>   
> ^C
>   
> --- github.com ping statistics ---
>   
> 9 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
>   
> Lillys-MacBook-Air:Yuewei Lilly$

1. I have ShadowSocks (proxy) turned on. Without it I can't access github.com via browser, with it, I can.
2. also when I do "git remote -v" I see both my pull and push remote repos correctly listed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The next time it happens to you, check for Github status in [twitter handler](https://twitter.com/githubstatus). If their twitter handle doesn't say that one of their servers down or something like that, chances are its some firewall that is stopping your access.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis thanks for the input. I second that!